# Where is the photon getting energy to deviate from its path?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, energy-conservation, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

[image]

If we make $\triangle$x really small, then in order to not break the Heisenberg uncertainty principle the photons will need to change momentum($\triangle$p), so where is it getting the energy to deviate? I know that wave function says that the position of the photon is probabilistic but still in order deviate wouldn't it need energy?

[image]

The photon that would have gone almost straight, would have required less energy than a photon that was detected in extreme right or left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Momentum is a vector. That vector is changed, not its magnitude. Otherwise we'd see a slit changing the wavelength of the photons. The change does cause a force on the barrier structure, but the barrier is not moving. If the barrier moved, there would be an energy transfer between photon and barrier, and the photon wavelength would change.

BTW, an interesting side effect of this fact is that if the barrier moved toward the source of photons, the resulting photons would have more energy.

Comment: Suppose we attach a ball to a string and make it go round over our head, we would only be changing the velocity vector's direction and not its magnitude but that too requires energy. So even if the magnitude of momentum vector is not changed , wouldn't changing the direction itself require energy?

Comment: Ideally the ball swinging around requires no energy. We add energy to that for practical reasons: air resistance and the friction of a short part of the string against the hand.

Comment: @Pranav K Digiproc is right, both in the answer to your question and in his comment. In both cases the velocity vector direction changes but not the energy. In the case of the ball you need energy **intially** to make it swing but when it reaches the  final velocity, no more energy is needed except to balance friction. Without friction you could just attach the string to some inert fixed object and let the ball swing around it.

Comment: @Alfred  what about gravity, without an extra energy input it would be a spiral down.

Comment: I feel this doesn't answer the question. Ok the photon has no change in energy, yet it still takes energy to change its momentum's direction, right? In CM you'd need to apply a torque, that requires energy!!!

Comment: @thermomagnetic, It is true a change in angular momentum requires a change in energy. However, the angular momentum did not change. One could think of it like this: the photon was redirected, but the re-director (the barrier) was not moving. It's like a thrown baseball that is redirected by a baseman without changing it's speed.

Comment: @annav Do you mean the photon ? With gravity it will follow a parabola down, but it  will in fact increase its energy from the gravitational potential. If you mean the bal on a string it will not "spiral down". Once it has received initially enough energy (that, it needs) the balance between gravity and centrifugal force will keep it on a plane trajectory, slightly below the fixed point of the string, so the resultant of gravity and centrifugal force goes just through this point. Without friction it will keep rotating there indefinitely without any extra input of energy.

Comment: A non interacting  with another article photon  does not change either energy or direction, it travels along within the Heisenberg uncertaity principle envelope, which can only be  tested if an interaction happens. This answer is about light, not photons.  barriers mean *interaction*

Comment: @Alfred  you cannot tie a photon. The ball will fall due to gravity, keeping angular momentum constant, that is why it will be a spiral

Comment: @annav I was commenting Pranav's answer and his comment. The commnet describes a totally different problem. I  am not sure what your comment is about.

Comment: @annav If we deal wit hthe original questio nad Pranv's answer, gravity has nothing to do with. For the record, the photon will indeed follow a parabola down but essentially one can ignore gravity and think of thr photo nas propagating horizontally

Comment: @annav Pranav tried to give a different example, but  I'm afraid it brought more confusion rather than a better  understanding. His point with which I agree is taht without friction you don't have to add energy to a ball going around a fixed point attached by a string. Sure, the circle described by the ball will be on a plane below the fixed point of the string, but **without friction** it will stay the same forever, without need of extra energy input.

Comment: @Alfred  if you do not give enough energy to counteract the balls's natural fall in the gravitational field of the earth, the whole thing will spiral down.

Comment: @annav Not if I am standing on the ground on my feet and hold the string above my head and have given it some initial spin and **there is not friction**. Then after the initial energy injection it will keep rotating on an plane a bit below my hand without any further input. Of course **no friction** is not possible in practice. I was just agreeing with Digiproc answer to Pranav's question (I got confused on an earlier answer to you ; it was Digiproc who answered, not Pranav)

Answer (score 1):

It is all quantum mechanic, i.e the Heisneberg uncertainty principle (HUP) is within the framework of quantum mechanics, not of classical particles running along on straight tracks.

What does it mean for a single photon? It means if one **measures** the $x$ coordinate very accurately, the $p$ component uncertainty is constrained by the HUP.

$ΔxΔp>h/{2π}$

The  HUP   says nothing about scattering, and the  changing paths that you draw.

[image: gamma]

In the above bubble chamber picture we see one photon ( a gamma) hitting an electron and coming out with a number of charged tracks. In bubble chambers the accuracy of measurements is microns, and the HUP is fulfilled automatically, as the accuracy of momentum measurement is in mev/c. The uncertainty in momentum will be within the measurement errors that will give the momentum of this gamma.

When a photon interacts, which it has to do if measured, it is then that one can check the HUP.

Edit:

Maybe you are confused by the [virtual loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_polarization) that can exist within the HUP envelope, of particle/antiparticle, in  vacuum . These because the particles are virtual the particle momenta are not on mass shell, and they continuously change under the integral that the loop represents. For momentum to change one needs a real interaction vertex, as the gamma electron scattering in the picture above.

Comment: see also my answer here for numbers  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/107397/how-are-cloud-chamber-tracks-consistent-with-the-uncertainty-principle/107442#107442

Answer (score 0):

The recoil energy is extremely small, but you are correct the in principle it is not exactly zero. The energy of the photon (eVs) is many orders of magnitude smaller than that of the slit system ($10^{26} $ eVs) .